# salesforce to java type conversion

Tags: java, spring, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I'm fetching data from salesforce to java using partner API . 
well upto here is no problem , but my concern is something annoying .
in my salesforec end i've one field, type of currency and suppose it has value  $850,000,000,000  ok 
now when i'm fetching data through partner in java like 
String value = (String)sobj.getField("MyFieldName");

i'll get 8.5E8.... thats wht i'm getting . 
now my question is 
1) if i'm getting data as String then why it cast to decimal automatically
2) and i couldn't cast it another type as well for example 
 BigInterger bi = (BigInteger)sobj.getField("MyFieldName");
gives  classcast Exception as well as
Double d = (Double)sobj.getField("MyFieldName"); too gives same exception 
moreover
Double d = new Double(sobj.getField("MyFieldName").toString()); 
again gives exponential value ...

please solve my issue , coz value in salesforce is too big in multi billions

Answer (score 0):

Try `Long bi = new BigInteger(sobj.getField("MyFieldName")).longValue()`

Also, you should read up on casting, I think you are confused about what it is and how it works.

Comment: no this is also not working first of all ur code is wrong,bcoz of the following resaons 1)  how longValue() returns BigInteger  2) BigInteger does not have constructor compatible with object type .  moreover thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, that's supposed to be `Long bi = new BigInteger(sobj.getField("MyFieldName")).longValue()`, forgot to change the type after adding `longValue()` as an afterthought. 
BigInteger constructor takes a string, which you have there with your "8.5E8". Just feed that string into the constructor.